# rubyで生成に時間のかかるattrの実装の仕方

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

現在このようなクラスがあります。

```
class Hoge
  attr_accessor :fuga, :piyo

  def initialize
    data_create
  end

  def data_create
    data = 色々な処理{...}

    # インスタンス変数に代入
    @fuga = data[:a]
    @piyo = data[:b]
  end
end

# 使う時
hoge = Hoge.new
hoge.hufa
hoge.piyo
```

`Hoge#datacreate`は実際には`http`経由で情報を取得してきたり、変換処理を行ったりしていて多少時間がかかってしまうものです。
そのため、インスタンスを生成する度にオーバーヘッドのコストがかかってしまいます。

Hogeクラスを使う時に必ず`@fuga`や`@piyo`を使うわけではないので、初めて参照されたタイミングでデータを作るようにすればいいと思いつきました。

具体的には以下のようなコードです。

```
class Hoge
  @fuga = nil
  @piyo = nil

  def fuga
    data_create if @fuga.nil?

    @fuga
  end

  def piyo
    data_create if @piyo.nil?

    @piyo
  end


  def data_create
    data = 色々な処理{...}

    # インスタンス変数に代入
    @fuga = data[:a]
    @piyo = data[:b]
  end
end


# 使う時
hoge = Hoge.new
hoge.hufa
hoge.piyo
```

まだプログラミングの経験が浅いため、このやり方が良い方法である自信がありません。
気をつけたほうがいい部分などがあれば、教えていただけないでしょうか。

みなさんの「自分だったらこうする」というアイディアなどもドンドンお聞かせください。

また、rubyらしく工夫できる書き方などもあれば教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`data`がどのような情報なのかわからないので見当違いになっているかもしれませんが、
私ならこんな感じに書きます。

```
class Hoge
  def fuga
    data[:a]
  end

  def piyo
    data[:b]
  end

  def data
    @data ||= 色々な処理{...}
  end
end
```

メソッド`data`が参照された時にインスタンス変数の`@data`が`nil`であれば`色々な処理`が実行され、既に値が入っていれば`@data`がそのまま返されるのですぐに返ってきます。